# Find the number formed by sorted digits that is closest to and smaller or equal to n.

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I am looking for an algorithm that takes a number **N** as an input and outputs a number with **base 10** that is:

1. The closest number to **N**
2. Made out of sorted digits from the smallest
   to the highest
3. And smaller or equal to **N**

Example:

Input -> Output

132 -> 129

1000 -> 999

111111111111111110 -> 99999999999999999

7 -> 7

Comment: How does $N=7$ yield $7$? That does not satisfy the "smaller than $N$" condition.

Comment: You're right, sorry for that mistake. It should be smaller or equal. I will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Locate the *leftmost* place in the number where a smaller digit follows a larger:

   ```
   ......ab...
   ```

   with $a>b$.
2. Replace the *first* digit $a$ in the number with $a-1$ and *all following digits* with $9$.

For example, in `111333555777444333888`, $ab$ is $74$, so we replace the *first* $7$ by $6$ and the rest with nines:

```
in:  111333555777444333888
out: 111333555699999999999
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer